# PHP Output Buffering Check?

Tags: php, output-buffering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - How Detect if Output Buffering is Turned On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608975/php-how-detect-if-output-buffering-is-turned-on)

How can I check in PHP if output_buffering is set to On? I have to troubleshoot a site and I have no access to the hosting panel.

Something like:

```
if(output_buffering == 'On')
{
    echo 'It is On';
}
else
{
    echo 'It is NOT On';
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php). I didn't test it, but I am pretty sure it will suit your needs since `ini_get()` is used for that purpose: checking php.ini options.

Comment: It should work to be tested with `if(ini_get('output_buffering')) { echo 'it is on'; }`

Comment: How about if you start output buffering from within your script? `ini_get('output_buffering') => false; ob_start(); ini_get('output_buffering') => false;`

Comment: The question is about the php.ini setting as you can see. Anyhow, in the situation you specified, Wrikken answer is surely golden!

Answer (score 11):

```
if(ob_get_level() > 0){
   //there are some buffers active.
}


$ php -d output_buffering=1 -r'var_dump(ob_get_level());'
int(1)
$ php -d output_buffering=0 -r'var_dump(ob_get_level());'
int(0)
```

It does however check whether there is an output buffer active, not what the actual setting of PHP itself is. A manual `ob_start()` (or more then one) will also increase the level. Usually this is more interesting then the actual `output_buffering` setting. If you actually need *that*, fo with the `ini_get` answer.