# PHP - How Detect if Output Buffering is Enabled

Tags: php, output-buffering

Is there a simple way to detect in PHP if output_buffering is *enabled* in php.ini? I'd like to be able to display a message if it is not enabled.

Within my application I tried using an htaccess file to automatically enable it but it seems it does not work in all server environments and in some cases it gives a nasty error.

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506411/php-output-buffering-check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check any INI setting in PHP with the `ini_get` method. http://php.net/ini_get

```
ini_get('output_buffering');
```

Likewise, you can change most INI settings with `ini_set`:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'on');
```

Answer (score 21):

You can access the `output_buffering` value in the php.ini file by doing:

```
var_dump(ini_get('output_buffering'));
```

But I think what you are looking for is [`ob_get_level()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php) (or [`ob_get_status()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php)):

```
var_dump(ob_get_level());
```

> Returns the level of nested output
>   buffering handlers **or zero if output
>   buffering is not active**.

Answer (score 1):

simple

check by

```
echo ini_get('output_buffering');
```

or run a file calling `phpinfo();` function it will list all veriables containing values check the value for 'output_buffering ' in list.

Answer (score -4):

I think you can go

```
if(!ob_start())
{
}
```